alpine linux | mounting media failed
I am trying to install apine lixun on a server. Use Rufus to create a bootable flash drive with the operating system.
When trying to install the operating system I get the following message "mounting boot media failed"
I tried the same pendrive and same SSD to install Ubuntu and it worked without problems. In this way I rule out that these are the ones that are causing my headache.
In the configuration file I only see this:
i need help to solution this problem

Let's suppose you are using Alpine 3.20.3 (latest available at the time of writing) and that you are using Windows OS on a x86_64 architecture.
Download the iso from the link:
https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.20/releases/x86_64/alpine-standard-3.20.3-x86_64.iso
Download also the sha256 sum of the file:
https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.20/releases/x86_64/alpine-standard-3.20.3-x86_64.iso.sha256
Open a powershell instance in the same dir you have downloaded the ISO and the SHA256 sum:
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Content -Path alpine-standard-3.20.3-x86_64.iso.sha256) -DifferenceObject (Get-FileHash alpine-standard-3.20.3-x86_64.iso -Algorithm SHA256).Hash.ToLower()
If the sha256sum  are the same, then you can proceed with several different tools that can create a bootable USBo from ISO:
Rufus as you have tried, maybe following this tutorial:
https://blog.tannernielsen.com/2020/12/27/how-to-make-an-alpine-linux-bootable-usb-with-persistence
Or ventoy (https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html), following this tutorial:
https://ostechnix.com/create-bootable-usb-drive-with-ventoy-webui-in-linux/
Or Balena Etcher, following this tutorial:
https://venenux.github.io/alpine-wiki/tutorials/alpine-install-from-usb-to-disk-pc-single-boot-only.html
